# How to use Powershell to update property of an entity in Azure Table Storage to null?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-table-storage

Lets say I have retrieved an entity from my table.
I want to set one of the property to null.
How can I do it?
This is what I did:

```
 $myData.PropertyOne = $null
 $myData | Update-AzureStorageTableRow -table $destStorageTable
```

But I got error:

> Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object." At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.21\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:629
>   char:13
>   + ...      return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException

Comment: What is the data type of `PropertyOne`?

Comment: It can be string, datetime or guid. But I don't think the datatype matters?

Comment: Datatype does matter. Azure Tables is schema-less key-value pair store so essentially it doesn't store null values (except for string data type I believe). Can you edit your question and share the object model.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it?

The problem is that because azure table storage does not have a schema, the null column actually doesn't exist. You could do something like store an empty string if you really have to.

```
 $myData.PropertyOne = ""
 $myData | Update-AzureStorageTableRow -table $destStorageTable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the column -

```
$myData.psobject.Properties.Remove('PropertyOne')
$myData | Update-AzureStorageTableRow -table $destStorageTable
```